# How to get max value after a sum from a DataFrame from Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://pycourse.s3.amazonaws.com/bike-sharing.csv")
```

And need to get know the 'hour' it has more 'total_count'. So I thought in sum the 'total_count' in each 'hour' and find out which hour has the max sum.

I already know that is hour 17 I did:

```
df.groupby(['hour'], as_index=False)['total_count'].sum().max()
```

But it gave me both max from 'hour'(without sum) and 'total_count'(with sum). So I did:

```
df.groupby(['hour'], as_index=False)['total_count'].sum().max()
```

And search it for the max value myself.

In this case was easy because it was only 23 rows to look at. But if I had more rows to look (like 100 or 1000) I wouldn't make it like this.

To sum up, I want to know how I could get the corresponding 'hour' for max 'total_count' after sum up all 'total_count' corresponding to each 'hour'.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some sample data and your desired output for us to work with.

Comment: How do I show that? I work with google colab how do I show you my output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  (edited to correct the columns ).

```
import pandas as pd

#create the dataframe
df = df = pd.read_csv("https://pycourse.s3.amazonaws.com/bike-sharing.csv")
#get the total_count summed by hour
df['hr_count'] = df.groupby('hour')['total_count'].sum()
#get the max total_count by hour
df = df.groupby('hour').agg({'hr_count':'max'}).reset_index()
#sort it
print(df.sort_values(by='hr_count',ascending=False))
```

outputs:

```
     hour  hr_count
17    17  336860.0
18    18  309772.0
8      8  261001.0
16    16  227748.0
19    19  226789.0
13    13  184919.0
12    12  184414.0
15    15  183149.0
14    14  175652.0
20    20  164550.0
9      9  159438.0
7      7  154171.0
11    11  151320.0
10    10  126257.0
21    21  125445.0
22    22   95612.0
23    23   63941.0
6      6   55132.0
0      0   39130.0
1      1   24164.0
2      2   16352.0
5      5   14261.0
3      3    8174.0
4      4    4428.0
```

Comment: Idk what happened but it didn't sum. Correct answer is 17h when all sum up. 18h just turns out to have one day with max total at that time.
Edit: How I can show my inputs and outputs like this to you guys?

Comment: Yep - edited the column to 'hr_count' which stored the sums per hour.

Comment: Ty dude. One guy in a wpp group also told me to use the function .nlargest(1, 'Value'). It seems simpler.

Comment: @BrunoHerrera - sure, you would still need to sum up and find out the max using `print(df.nlargest(3, 'hr_count'))`  which will show first three largest count.